# ObservableAsPropertyHelper doesn't fire any notification

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have this simple ViewModel.

```
public class FrameProcessingViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<LightWeight> currentDetectionExposer;

    public FrameProcessingViewModel(UnitFactory factory)
    {
        var identifications = factory.Units.SelectMany(unit => unit.Identifications);

        identifications.ToProperty(this, model => model.CurrentDetection, out currentDetectionExposer);
        identifications.Subscribe();
    }

    public LightWeight CurrentDetection => currentDetectionExposer.Value;
}
```

I have a Binding in the view to the CurrentDetection property, but it doesn't update. It's always null and I don't understand why.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

OK, I have discovered what was the problem. The only "unit" item that was arriving did it BEFORE the ToProperty call was made, so the underlying subscription of the currentDetectionExposer was made AFTER the item arrived and no update ever happened.

My observable depends on 2 sources that are ISubject. I solve it making both of them ReplaySubjects, so their values are pushed everytime a subscription is made and not it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me - are you sure that your identificactions observable ever produces a value?

A couple of additional notes:  The identifications.Subscribe() is not necessary - ToProperty does a subscribe internally that causes your observable to begin producing values if it's cold.  Also, you will generally want to put an ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler) before the ToProperty(..) to make sure that values produced on a background don't accidentally cause the UI to be updated from a non-dispatcher thread

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }
}


public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<long> _propertyHelper;

    public ViewModel(IObservable<long> factory)
    {
        factory.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).ToProperty(this, model => model.Property, out _propertyHelper);
    }

    public long Property => _propertyHelper.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have discovered what was the problem. The only "unit" item that was arriving did it BEFORE the ToProperty call was made, so the underlying subscription of the currentDetectionExposer was made AFTER the item arrived and no update ever happened.

My observable depends on 2 sources that are ISubject. I solve it making both of them ReplaySubjects, so their values are pushed everytime a subscription is made and not it works!